# In lua I see the print function use ..var.. and I wonder what the periods mean?

Tags: user-interface, scripting, lua, iup

Here is an example:
print("PARAM"..param_index.." = "..param.value)

What the heck are those weird periods in there?

Comment: That periods are not weird.  These definitely are: `print(... .. ...)`

Answer (score 7):

[String concatenation](http://www.lua.org/pil/3.4.html).

What else would you expect??

Comment: +1 for "what else would you expect?", this question really shows complete illiteracy and lack of effort.

Comment: @user1813997 If you'd read the FAQ, you'd have seen that you are supposed to put some effort into attempting to find the answer yourself before asking a question. And since this is something that's mentioned in practically all lua tutorials out there (the not terrible ones anyway), there is no way you actually attempted to look this up yourself before asking. This isn't twitter, the people here are relatively sensitive to noise.